# how do you create bar charts for two different data columns and one group cloumn

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data frame:

```
dput(head(x,3))
structure(list(Programs = structure(1:3, .Label = c("400.perlbench", 
"401.bzip2", "403.gcc", "429.mcf", "445.gobmk", "456.hmmer", 
"458.sjeng", "462.libquantum", "464.h264ref", "471.omnetpp", 
"473.astar", "483.xalancbmk"), class = "factor"), Base_Run_Time = c(988.746037, 
1401.357446, 821.134215), Base_Rate = c(790.49624, 550.8944, 
784.28104), Base_Geo_Mean = c(837.6709, 837.6709, 837.6709), 
    Bench_Mark_Run_Time = c(827.236707, 1329.663649, 818.863431
    ), Peak_Rate = c(944.83232, 580.59792, 786.45592), Chip = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("E5_2660", "E7_4860", "ultrasparc"), class = "factor"), 
    Bench_Geo_Mean = c(790.4498, 790.4498, 790.4498), Percent_Difference = c(0.06, 
    0.06, 0.06)), .Names = c("Programs", "Base_Run_Time", "Base_Rate", 
"Base_Geo_Mean", "Bench_Mark_Run_Time", "Peak_Rate", "Chip", 
"Bench_Geo_Mean", "Percent_Difference"), row.names = c(NA, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to create a bar chart where for each group, need to have Base_Run_Time and Bench_Mark_Run_Time side by side, one having orange and the other having blue color.

I have tried something like this, but this gives me a stack chart. I need bar chart for each Base_Run_Time and Bench_Mark_Run_Time:

```
ggplot(x)+geom_bar(data=x, aes(Programs, Base_Run_Time, colour="orange", group=Chip), stat="identity") + geom_bar(data=x, aes(Programs,Bench_Mark_Run_Time, colour="blue", fill="green", group=Chip), stat="identity")
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should melt your data from wide to long format and then plot your data. With `position="dodge"` you can set that bars are side by side. From melted data frame use `value` for the y values and the `variable` for the fill. With `scale_fill_manual()` you can get desired colors.

```
library(reshape2)
xx <- melt(x, id = "Programs",measure.vars = c("Base_Run_Time", "Bench_Mark_Run_Time"))
       Programs            variable     value
1 400.perlbench       Base_Run_Time  988.7460
2     401.bzip2       Base_Run_Time 1401.3574
3       403.gcc       Base_Run_Time  821.1342
4 400.perlbench Bench_Mark_Run_Time  827.2367
5     401.bzip2 Bench_Mark_Run_Time 1329.6636
6       403.gcc Bench_Mark_Run_Time  818.8634

ggplot(xx,aes(Programs,value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange","blue"))
```

[image]